# Do not work bash script and Imagemagic convert But command is correct

Tags: bash, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have the following code and when I run it on a file, I get the convert's help message

```
#!/bin/bash

help () {
  printf "Parchos Arts convert script \n"
  printf "Syntax: convert_to_all_size file [-h]\n"
  printf "* file:\t\t\t\t A mandatory argument and must be a image\n"
  printf "* -h: \t\t\t\t Show this message\n"
}

if [ "$1" == "" ];then
  help
  exit 1
fi

filename=$(basename -- "$1")
extension="${filename##*.}"
filename="${filename%.*}"
dirname="$(dirname $(readlink -e $1))"

sizes=( '1600x1200'
  '1280x1024'
  '440x247'
  '1080x1920'
  '1680x1050'
  '1024x768'
  '1366x768'
  '3200x2000'
  '3200x1800'
  '2560x1600'
  '3840x2160'
  '720x1440'
  '5120x2880'
  '2560x1440'
  '1280x800'
  '360x720'
  '1920x1200'
  '1440x900'
  '1920x1080'
)

if file "$1" | grep -qE 'image|bitmap'; then
  mkdir $dirname/sizes
  for size in ${sizes[@]};do
    echo "converting to $size..."
    convert "$1 -resize $size\> $dirname/sizes/$size.$extension"
  done
  
else
  echo "The $1 file is not a photo, please use a photo."
  exit 1
fi
```

```bash
$  ./tools/convet_to_all_size Logo/parch_1000x_logo.png
```

Output:

```
...  
converting to 1920x1080...
convert Logo/parch_1000x_logo.png -resize 1920x1080\> /home/mmdbalkhi/w/parch/artwork/artwork/Logo/sizes/1920x1080.png
```

And I write an echo in front of the line that contains the convert command and I execute it manually and everything works!

```bash
$ convert Logo/parch_1000x_logo.png -resize 1920x1080\> /home/mmdbalkhi/w/parch/artwork/artwork/Logo/sizes/1920x1080.png

$ ls Logo/sizes
# 1920x1080.png
```

Where is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: Why the second _echo_ command inside the for loop? Does the script work if you remove that word?

Comment: Edited. I used it in my debug because of that And I forgot to remove this when I send it and no not worked

Comment: Does the program work correctly now?

Comment: Why the quotation marks after convert?

Comment: @zipzit That was the problem! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because of the quotation mark after the convert command! Thanks to [@zipzit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2487730/zipzit)